# Power Automate - Send Email (V2) - link to sharepoint list with dynamic content

Tags: power-automate, dynamic-content

I have a flow that sends out a email requesting that an update is done to the outcome of training done earlier in the day.

I have had this working at one stage but if I so much as look at it it seems to break and I can not get it to work again.

Hoping someone can help me out or if you know a better way that would be great to.

Below is how it looks when not working.

[image]

Please update the status of the training session through the link below
Link: @{outputs('Compose_7')}%20@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Date']}&PRACA=@{variables('Practical Assessment')}">Training Status Update

The process I follow to add the link is,

Step 1

Insert Link:

Link = https://Sharepointlink.com/sites/OSTraining/Lists/Mine%20Training%20Status/NewForm.aspx?INFO=INSERT...Date&PRACA=INSERTPracticalAssessment

Title = TrainingStatusUpdate (no spaces)

Step 2

Dummy add in variables / add space in for Training Status Update

I hope the above infomation makes sense as I don't use power automate much.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.